# Why isn't addTarget calling my target's action in an extension

Tags: swift

I don't think the reason for the lack of calling is the fact that I'm doing it in an extension, but I can't think of any other reason why this isn't working:

**Extension:**

```
extension UIControl
{
    func function(controlEvent: UIControlEvents)
    {
        let test = Test()
        addTarget(test, action: Selector("update"), forControlEvents: controlEvent)
    }
}
```

**Class**

```
class Test
{
    func update()//(input: U)
    {
        print("worl")
    }
}
```

When I set the target to self and declare the action within the extension, it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

I'm calling the function in the initial viewcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tf = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
    view.addSubview(tf)
    tf.function(.AllEditingEvents)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifetime of your variable `test` is limited to the scope of the function `function` that creates it. After that method returns, `test` goes out of scope and is deallocated, so it's not there for later control events to send actions to.  (To put it another way, `addTarget(_:action:forControlEvents:)` does not retain the target.)

You'll need to find a way to make `test` persist outside of the function. You can't add stored properties in a class extension, though, so you'll have to do it another way. Perhaps a computed property whose accessors read/write to something global?

Also, this might not be part of the problem, but just to be safe: target/action selectors are expected to have a single parameter (the control that sends the action), so your `update()` method should be `update(sender: AnyObject)`, and the selector for it should be `update:`.